# ident vs md5 for Postgres authentication

Tags: postgresql

I set up a Postgres db server on CentOS and created a database, `mydb`.

I access `psql` as system user `postgres` and check to see that it exists:

```
$ sudo -u postgres -i
$ psql
postgres=# \l

 Name | Owner | ...    
--------------------
 mydb | postgres | ...
```

I then configure it:

(1) `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` is uncommented in `postgresql.conf`.

(2) I set the password for user `postgres`.

```
sudo -u postgres psql template1
ALTER USER postgres with encrypted password 'my_password';
```

But, connection via `psql -U postgres -h localhost` and Pgadm3 fail with this error:

```
Ident autentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I checked `/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_hba.conf`.

`ident` is the default method for local `IPv6` and `IPv4` connections.

I change this from `ident` to `md5`.

Then, connection via Pgadmi3 and `psql` work as expected

Why does `ident` fail?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-methods.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It fails due to:

> The ident authentication method works by obtaining the client's
>   **operating system user name** from an ident server and using it as the
>   allowed database user name (with an optional user name mapping). This
>   is only supported on TCP/IP connections.

The `ident` should mean *UNIX identification*. In order to `ident` work you must run `psql` or `PGAdmin` by `postgres` user (default Postgres processes owner on CentOS). So make sure you made `sudo su - postgres` or `sudo - postgres` (and it works as you shown).

The `md5` actually means *md5 hash password identification*. For me personally it easiest way.

I'm sure in your example everything works correctly :-)